# DAX / PowerPivot overlapping of three periods in time

Tags: excel, datetime, excel-2013, powerpivot, dax

I am trying to calculate the effective duration of an event as a calculated column with something like:
[total duration of event] - [out of office hours overlapping the event] - [system downtime during office hours]
and I can't figure out how this can be done

OfficeHoursTable:

```
date - office hours start time - office hours end time - is working day
01/01/2017 - 08:00 am - 08:00 pm - 0
02/01/2017 - 08:00 am - 08:00 pm - 1
...
09/01/2017 - 08:00 am - 08:00 pm - 1
10/01/2017 - 08:00 am - 08:00 pm - 1
11/01/2017 - 08:00 am - 08:00 pm - 1
...
```

SystemDowntimeTable:

```
date - system downtime start time - system downtime end time
01/01/2017 - 08:17 am - 9:43 am
10/01/2017 - 7:00 pm - 8:00 pm
```

EventsTable:

```
EventID - start datetime - end datetime - effective duration
1 - 01/01/2017 7:40 am - 01/01/2017 8:40 am - 0; Comment: 0 is because though there was a dowtime of the system overlapping this event, the event itself was during non working day
2 - 09/01/2017 7:40 am - 11/01/2017 11:00 am - 24; Comment: [total duration of event] - [out of office hours overlapping the event] - [system downtime during office hours] = 24 hours
3 -
```

I want this effective duration calculated column to be in EventsTable

As you can imagine there is much of an overlapping and time intelligence going on, I just can't wrap my head around this.

I am running PowerPivot for Excel 2013

Comment: Anyone? I know it is a challenging question, but it is doable, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm tinkering with this too; here's my initial thoughts on what feels like a brute-force approach:

1. Make a main hours table with all of the hours enumerated between your min
   datetime and max datetime in the data set

   2. Join your downtime hours on to that table, to flag each hour as "up"/"down"
   3. Join your office hours on to your main hours table to flag each as "working"/"out of office"
   4. Make a calculated column valid_hours in your hours table that is 1 if "up"&"working" else 0
   5. For each event, you can then do a column formula in DAX of the form:

in_scope_event_hours = CALCULATE(SUM(hours_table[valid_hours]),FILTER(hours_table,hours_table[datetime]>=event[start]&&hours_table[datetime]<=event[end]))